# Chrome Developer Tools Error

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a problem when using Chrome Developer tools that happens on occasions and prevents me from using it. I have added screenshot showing that when I open the tools, I get a jQuery error that stops me from loading the page, or will load the page but will prevent me from doing anything with the tool.

Please take a look and let me know what I need to disable, delete, anything to stop this problem. Thank you.

Link to screenshot: https://skitch.com/e-pertrai1/eqjfw/semsdesign.me-2012-08-23-how-to-install-make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please press the blue button at the bottom of the devtools window.

It is changing break on exception mode.

In your case it needs to be black.